# How to see changes in flutter app when changing values in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, real-time, stream-builder

[image]

I am trying to make these rolling switches to change its value whenever I do any change in Firebase realtime database.

To be more specific, whenever I change the value of Relay1/Data to 0, I want that switch to become inactive.

I've tried and looked everywhere, but I couldn't find any solution.

```
  bool relay1pressed;
  final databaseReferenceTest = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();



@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    databaseReferenceTest
        .child('MedicalCenter')
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      String value = snapshot.value['Relay1']['Data'];
      print('Value is $value');
      if (value == '1') {
        relay1pressed = true;
      } else
        relay1pressed = false;

      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
    });
  }

  
//Widget build

            StreamBuilder(
              stream: databaseReferenceTest
                  .child('MedicalCenter')
                  .child('Relay1')
                  .onValue,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
                databaseReferenceTest
                    .child('MedicalCenter')
                    .once()
                    .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                  String value = snapshot.value['Relay1']['Data'];
                  print('Value is $value');
                  if (value == '1') {
                    relay1pressed = true;
                    print('relay1 bool $relay2pressed');
                  } else {
                    relay1pressed = false;
                    print('relay1 bool $relay2pressed');
                  }
                });

                return LiteRollingSwitch(
                  value: relay1pressed,
                  textOn: 'active',
                  textOff: 'inactive',
                  colorOn: Colors.deepOrange,
                  colorOff: Colors.blueGrey,
                  iconOn: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
                  iconOff: Icons.power_settings_new,
                  onChanged: (bool state) {
                    state
                        ? databaseReferenceTest
                            .child('MedicalCenter')
                            .update({'Relay1/Data': '1'})
                        : databaseReferenceTest
                            .child('MedicalCenter')
                            .update({'Relay1/Data': '0'});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're currently using `once()` to get the value from the database, which means it only reads the current value. If you want to keep monitoring the value, you'll want to use `onValue` instead.

```
databaseReferenceTest
    .child('MedicalCenter')
    .onValue.listen((event) {
      var snapshot = event.snapshot

      String value = snapshot.value['Relay1']['Data'];
      print('Value is $value');

      ...

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Puf for your reply ! :)

it did work but sometimes i have to keep changing the values until it works again , i believe i have to add async or await somewhere?

Im sorry i just started learning flutter and im still figuring things out :D

Comment: I really appreciate your answers as they helped me a lot ! :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
databaseReferenceTest
.child('MedicalCenter')
.onValue.listen((event) {
  var snapshot = event.snapshot;
  setState(() {
    String value = snapshot.value['Relay1']['Data'];
  print('Value is $value');
  });
});
```

this should work...
I just added setState,

Comment: Can you tell us why it works? What is setState doing that was missing before?

Comment: setState for refresh the layout,  so if Text that takes value from >String value = snapshot.value [' Relay1 '] [' Data '];< will change too